# ffmpeg says that "'.mkv' is not a suitable output format"

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have trouble with `ffmpeg`, I want to do a two-pass encoding, plus denoise and deblock if possible.

This is a command I thought would work but I am getting all sorts of problems:

```
ffmpeg -y -i file.avi -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 2500k 
-filter:v hqdn3d=3:2:2:2:3:3 -pass 1 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 96k -f .mkv /dev/null && \ 
-i file.avi -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 2500k -filter:v hqdn3d=3:2:2:2:3:3 \
-pass 2 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 96k out.mkv
```

Right now I am getting this error

```
Requested output format '.mkv' is not a suitable output format
/dev/null: Invalid argument
```

I was getting an error about `hqdn3d=3:2:2:2:3:3` as well.

Full output

```
'/home/levan/bin/ffmpeg' -y -i '/home/levan/Downloads/file.avi' -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 2500k -filter:v hqdn3d=3:2:2:2:3:3 -pass 1 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 96k -f .mkv /dev/null && \ -i '/home/levan/Downloads/file.avi' -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 2500k -filter:v hqdn3d=3:2:2:2:3:3 -pass 2 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 96k out.mkv
ffmpeg version 2.4.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov  1 2014 23:29:20 with gcc 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/levan/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/levan/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/levan/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/levan/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      54. 11.100 / 54. 11.100
  libavcodec     56. 10.100 / 56. 10.100
  libavformat    56. 11.101 / 56. 11.101
  libavdevice    56.  2.100 / 56.  2.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.101 /  5.  2.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mpeg4 @ 0x34be860] Video uses a non-standard and wasteful way to store B-frames ('packed B-frames'). Consider using a tool like VirtualDub or avidemux to fix it.
Input #0, avi, from '/home/levan/Downloads/file.avi':
  Duration: 00:10:48.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17155 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (DX50 / 0x30355844), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 17020 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 30k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
[NULL @ 0x34de8a0] Requested output format '.mkv' is not a suitable output format
/dev/null: Invalid argument
levan@Commodore64:~$
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**`-f .mkv` should be `-f matroska`.**

See `ffmpeg -formats` (or `ffmpeg -muxers` for muxers only) for a list of supported names.

`ffmpeg` can automatically determine the appropriate format from the output file name, so most users can omit the `-f` option. Outputting to `/dev/null` or `NUL` is an exception.

Comment: I think "You do not need to encode audio in the first pass." may be incorrect now.  The example in the docs suggests you state an audio codec in the first pass, [Two-Pass Example](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Two-PassExample), because "In pass 1, specify the audio codec used in pass 2; in many cases, `-an` in pass 1 will not work.".  I am not sure why.

Comment: @zero298 I don't know either. Whoever added that never added an explanation, reasoning, or link to a bug to back up that claim, I don't recall ever having any issues (but I almost never do two-pass), and I never investigated that claim. Just did a quick two-pass test without audio in first pass and it was fine. Maybe there is a related bug report, but I didn't look for it.